# How to make resource pooling in Java?

Tags: java, resources, pooling

I have to maintain an app that create often resources and use them a very short time. So, most of the (precious *user*) time is spent in creating resources rather than actually using them.

I'd like to put those resources into a pool for grabbing them faster. I'm looking for a Java API that would permit me to do resource pooling (ie generic object pooling). I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I have found [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) for doing so in a Java application quite easily (as I have read the sample code so far).

After googling, it seems hard to find any other except the well known C3PO, Proxool etc.
Those latest do Connection pooling !

Do you know other APIs on the market that address the same need ?

Requirements :

- Production ready
- Well documented
- Lastest release should not be more than two years old
- Open/Close Source accepted
- Free/Paid Licence accepted
- Available in a Maven repository

Comment: What are you looking for which is not present in Apache's library?

Comment: According to the websitem ACP 1.6 is ~4 months old ... not over 2 years old.

Comment: I did a Google search for "java pool library" and I think I saw 4 different generic pooling libraries in the first page of search results.  Please don't expect us to do your research for you.

Comment: http://programming.huyduong.com/poolit/

Comment: Have used ACP a few times in the past and it has always worked great for me.  Setting up a JMX service allows you to tweak some of the pool parameters on the fly to get an ideal configuration for your needs.

Comment: @StephenC They are all Connection or Thred pool... I've already made this same search though.

Comment: I suspect you need a very light weight resource pool.  As such you could make a custom pool which is tailored to your needs to make it as light weight as possible. If you don't do this, you risk making the pool more heavy weight than creating new objects on demand.

Comment: Are you sure you really want a pool? It sounds to me like you are actually looking for a cache. In which case [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) may be what you are looking for. Start with just the core.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon My resources need to be released after a given timeout.

Comment: @Stephan - ehcache can do that.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I need a pool because my code won't create and delete resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I come up with those two libraries.

- [PoolIt](http://programming.huyduong.com/poolit/index.html)
- [ACP](http://commons.apache.org/pool/)